# Is it possible to add data to the related table after batch insert in Lumen/Laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen, csv-import

I am stuck with this problem. I have two tables `users` and `user_credentials` which are related to each other by `Id` column of the `users` table. Since I'm importing data from csv file, I'm using the `insert()` method to insert data in the users table instead of `create()` inside loop (which is a little bit faster I guess).

Is there any way to get the user id of the user for `user_credentials` table so that I'll be able to use `insert()` in this table as well

```
// begin DB transaction
            DB::beginTransaction();

            // loop through the data
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                // eliminate the first row
                if ($key == 0)
                    continue;

                // check for phone number validation
                if (!isset($value[2]) || $value[2] != null || $value[2] != '')
                    $phoneNumberValidation = null;

                // phone number validation
                $phoneNumberValidation = $this->validateNumber($value[2]);

                if ($phoneNumberValidation != false) {
                    $user = $this->user::Where('personal_number', $phoneNumberValidation)
                        ->first();

                    if ($user)
                        continue;
                }

                // create the user
                $users[] = [
                    'first_name' => $value[0],
                    'last_name' => $value[1],
                    'username' => 'oisf' . $userId++,
                    'email' => $value[9],
                    'password' => Hash::make($value[3]),
                    'address' => $value[4],
                    'personal_number' => $phoneNumberValidation,
                    'post_address' => $value[5],
                    'grad' => $value[6],
                    'forb' => $value[7],
                    'offk' => (empty(trim($value[8]))) ? 0 : $value[8],
                    'approval_date' => ($value[10] != '') ? Carbon::parse($value[10])->startOfDay()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') : Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
                    'samtycke' => false,
                    'status' => 'approved',
                    'role_id' => ($role) ? $role->id : $newRole->id,
                    'member' => ($value[10] != '') ? $value[10] : Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'),
                    'note' => $value[11],
                    'payment_status' => isset($value[12]) && !empty($value[12]) ? $value[12] : 'unpaid',
                    'username_id' => $userId
                ];

                // I need to change this
                UserCredential::create([
                    'user_id' => 'i want user id here',
                    'some_column_name' => $value['some_key']
                ]);

                // to this
                $userCredentials[] = [
                   'user_id' => 'i want user id here',
                   'some_column_name' => $value['some_key']
                ];
            }

            $this->user::insert($users);

            // and then after above insert, I would like to use
            UserCredential::insert($userCredentials);

            // commit the transaction
            DB::commit();
```

Comment: Also It would be of great help if you could help me optimize this method

Comment: I think its better to use the `create()` method so than you can get the `ID` on the go then use a relational model so that it is faster to insert record on the `user_credentials`. And also you can change your validation to fail first before continue so that the process will get shorter.

Comment: So there isn't any way to achieve this without using create()

Comment: I think there is but myself can't think of any raw method to put this into that way. Unless you can search for a function that can get the `ID` on the go without changing your method. Also try other methods like `map()` I think it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try use `DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();`, it will get the last inserted id, so if you use that before inserting into UserCredential, you should get the last id.

Comment: You didn't get my question